# Problema com redirecionamento em JSF 2

Tags: java, jsf

Em um projeto JSF as páginas estão organizadas assim:

- admin/pages
- admin/main
- admin/template.

Meu web.xml está assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>ararazul</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/admin/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Criei uma classe para encapsular o redirecionamento de acordo com o caso de uso.

```
package br.com.ararazul.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

/**
 *
 * Classe responsável por abstrair as navegações do Sistema
 * 
 * @author Hugo Sousa
 * 
 * */
public class NavigationUtil {

    public static final String PAGESFOLDER = "admin";
    public static final String INITIALPAGE = "index";

    /**
     * 
     * Método responsável por forçar o redirecionamento para uma determinada
     * página no contexto do caso de uso em questão
     * 
     * @author Hugo Sousa
     * @param casoDeUso
     * @param pagina
     * @throws IOException 
     * 
     * */
    public static void redirecionar(String casoDeUso, String pagina) {

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        String contexto = facesContext.getExternalContext().getContextName();
        try {
            if(pagina.equals(INITIALPAGE)) {
                facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("/" + contexto);
            } else {
                facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("/" + contexto + "/" + PAGESFOLDER + "/" + casoDeUso + "/" + pagina + ".xhtml");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Só que há um loop no redirecionamento sempre que acesso a aplicação. Eu usei apenas uma chamada a um método de um controller para chamar a index no menu do sistema: `#{controller.index()}` e quando tiro essa chamada a página carrega normalmente.

Comment: use o "?faces-redirect=true" no final da url.

Answer (score 0):

Tente remover a chamada {controller.index()} e adicione esse código no seu web.xml.

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Já fiz isso no web.xml.
E essa entrada é para quando eu estiver noutra página e chamar a página inicial.